# What extra things should one report when including random effects?

Tags: mixed-model, reporting

If I include random effects for each subject in my regression, and I have 20+ subjects, what should I include in my report?

The estimates of each effect, and what else? What about model diagnostics?

The main interest lies in the other fixed effects, not so much on the random effects, but I still feel I should say something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to justify that exchangeability is reasonable. I.e. that a-priori you cannot know whether the value of the parameter on which you have the random effect (e.g. the intercept) would be higher or lower for certain units (e.g. subjects) compared to others.

In terms of analyses, predictive checks would make sense to me. I.e. if you simulate, do you get near-nominal coverage of prediction intervals?